# Archiving file notfound

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to archive an app and the problem is that the Archive succeeded but the archive file is not displayed in organizer or anywhere were I look. Please, can any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the organizer in the Archives tab, right-click to open the finder folder containing the archive. They will be in a folder under: "/Volumes/User/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 4.0 and 4.2 you will get your archive file on clicking window >> organizer >> archives.

Comment: Hi As i said, In Archives i am not finding the archived file even though the Archive is succeeded

Comment: Please spell out full words and sentences on Stack Overflow.  This isn't a text message.